# how keystone compile front end javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystone

I am studying keystone now.
In browser, I found there is a js file item.js. The file's content seems come from different. So I take a look on source code at keystone/admin/src/views/item.js
In this file, there are several require calls.
So I guess the final item.js is a result of compilation.

My question is who did the compile job and when?

Answer (score 0):

Probably [browserify](http://browserify.org/) having had a quick look at the [package.json](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/package.json) file.

Comment: thanks, at the mean while, I find browserify at keystone/admin/app folder.